# paper rejected, submitted to another conference, got accepted again by the first, what to do?

Tags: publications, conference

I have submitted my research work for a conference in data science, after two months of review it got weak rejection. So I decided to submit it to another conference (the submission was closed so I contacted the chair asking them if it possible and they reopened the submission system for me because I have a positive record with them and multiple publication for the last ten years). The first conference is A ranked and the other is B.

Now, the first conference contacted me telling me that I can submit my work to their symposium and the paper will be appeared as normal full paper in the final indexing.  My paper now is already under the review process with the B ranked conference. But, I would love to have in my records a publication with the first A ranked conference.

Can I contact the second conference again and ask them to cancel my submission? is such a thing acceptable in academia? because I am really looking to have the record with the first one. I am in my final year in the phd and will not publish anything soon because I am planing to start my thesis soon.

Comment: The outcome "weak reject" seems rather unusual. What was the precise wording from the notification? Was it clear that your paper might eventually still be accepted?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper the precise wording was rejection from the main track because of three weak rejections...so, its clear rejection for the main conference.

Comment: Then your paper was rejected (and not "weak rejected"), and later invited for publication at the symposium. A symposium publication is worth much less than a publication at the main conference. Are you sure that it will be published at the main conference? "Normal full paper" could also be at the symposium. –

Comment: @lighthousekeeper thats right, but checking into there last year IEEE digital library record for the main conference track and the symposium track both got credited and indexed as papers in the main conference track. as shown here: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conhome/9058428/proceeding

Comment: The symposium is unlikely to be ranked; it's a different conference.   Usually, the symposium/workshop is held in conjunction with the flagship conference it is setup to catch weak reject papers, and gain more registration fee.  The assumption is that the authors will make the corrections and undergo another round of review.  The submitted papers are treated as new.

Comment: If this would be my field I would (money allowing) go to both conferences. But I feel data science is something different. In all case I would attend and submit to the conference that has reopened the submission for you.

Comment: This should not have happened. Concurrent publishing is not a crime nor a sin, but unethical. However, communicating to the editors would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is indeed a bad practice to cancel a submission, especially if some days have elapsed and the review process has started. The editor might have already dedicated significant time examining the submission, finding and assigning appropriate reviewers for its topic, etc. It is even possible that he has already sent it to reviewers and that they have already started their review.

In your case, since I understand that you asked for your paper to be reviewed as a favour after the submission system had already closed, it might even be slightly worse, since the editor made an exception for you.

If you are really sure that appearing in the symposium of the first conference is important for you and your career, you can probably indeed ask for a second favour from the second conference's chair. If you do so, I would recommend explaining the situation and apologising quite profusely. I would suggest ensuring that in your explanation it is clear that conference A is a unique and important opportunity for you.

Personally, I would be somewhat annoyed, but I wouldn't consider it unacceptable. Make sure, also, that the chair has no reason to believe that you submitted the paper to his conference while it was still under review for the first one. That would indeed be unacceptable, and could do great damage to your reputation.

Also, before you do this, you should probably make sure that you understand the terms in which you would be accepted into the first conference. Being accepted into the symposium is likely not the same thing as being accepted into the main track; and it might be treated very differently from an indexing or a rating perspective.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is, to be honest. Tell this immediately to the second one. You can choose or decide upon the further course of action once the first is done.